# Final Rendered Video is Sped Up Compared to Animation Played in Processing

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, processing, render

Recently I made an Audio Visualizer in Processing. From there I wanted to render the animation created in Processing into a mp4 file. I am on a windows computer, and am using ffmpeg to convert my TIF files produced in Processing into mp4.

When I do this I am able to render the images into an mp4 file, but when I playback this file the animation is sped up compared to the animation when I play it on Processing. Because of this the animation does not sync with the audio when I combine the mp4 file and audio on a video editing program.

When I set my frame rate to 25 and have the limit on the number of frames to be 250 and render it into a mp4 file it is 10 seconds long like it should be, but it contains more than 10 seconds of the animation when compared to the animation played directly in Processing.

I have no idea why this is so any help will be much appreciated.

My Processing code:

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer player;
PImage img;
FFT fft;

void setup() {
  size(728, 546);

  minim = new Minim(this);

  // this loads mysong.wav from the data folder as a stream with a internal buffer of size 1024
  player = minim.loadFile("new_years_good.mp3");
  fft = new FFT(player.bufferSize(), player.sampleRate());
  player.play();
  img= loadImage("cat-in-shades-.jpg");
  frameRate(25);
}

void draw() {


  image(img, 0, 0);
  //tint(0, 100, 150);
  stroke(255);

  strokeWeight(4);
  float a = 0;

  float angle = (2*PI) / 200;


  fft.forward(player.mix);


  for(int i=0; i < player.bufferSize() - 1; i++) {

   //player.mix.get(i) is a value between [-1,1]

    float x = 250 + cos(a) * (20 * player.mix.get(i) + 100);
    float x2 = 540 + cos(a) * (20 * player.mix.get(i) + 100);    

    float y = 230 + sin(a) * (20 * player.mix.get(i) + 100);
    float y2 = 240 + sin(a) * (20 * player.mix.get(i) + 100);


    float xFinal = 250 + cos(a+angle) * (20 * player.mix.get(i+1) + 100);
    float x2Final = 540 + cos(a+angle) * (20 * player.mix.get(i+1) + 100);


    float yFinal = 230 + sin(a+angle) * (20 * player.mix.get(i+1) + 100);    
    float y2Final = 240 + sin(a+angle) * (20 * player.mix.get(i+1) + 100);    


    line(x,y,xFinal,yFinal);
    line(x2,y2,x2Final,y2Final);
    a += angle;  



  }
  noStroke();  
  fill(255, 0, 0, 128);
  for(int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
  {
    float b = fft.getBand(i);
    float yAxis = random(-b, b) + 480;
    float xAxis = i*3;
    ellipse(xAxis, yAxis, b, b);
  }
  saveFrame("frame-####.tif");
  if(frameCount>250)
    {
      noLoop();
      stop();
    }

}

void stop() {
  player.close();
  minim.stop();

  super.stop();
}
```

What I input into the command line (as one line) on the cmd:

```
C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Processing\AudioVisulizer>ffmpeg -i C:\Users\Robert\Do
cuments\Processing\AudioVisulizer\frame-%04d.tif -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p smallVid
.mp4
```

What it outputted:

```
    ffmpeg version N-77836-g62dfe1d Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
      configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
    isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
    le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
    enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
    ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
    le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
    able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --ena
    ble-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
     --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
    e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --
    enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
      libavutil      55. 13.100 / 55. 13.100
      libavcodec     57. 22.100 / 57. 22.100
      libavformat    57. 21.101 / 57. 21.101
      libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
      libavfilter     6. 23.100 /  6. 23.100
      libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
      libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
      libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
    Input #0, image2, from 'C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Processing\AudioVisulizer\fram
    e-%04d.tif':
      Duration: 00:00:10.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
        Stream #0:0: Video: tiff, rgb24, 728x546, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
    AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] profile High, level 3.0
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] 264 - core 148 r2638 7599210 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
    ec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r
    ef=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
    _ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
    p=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 deci
    mate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_
    adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=2
    5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.6
    0 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    Output #0, mp4, to 'smallVid.mp4':
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavf57.21.101
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 728x54
    6, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc57.22.100 libx264
        Side data:
          unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (tiff (native) -> h264 (libx264))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    frame=   52 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=      77kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=
    frame=   74 fps= 65 q=28.0 size=     127kB time=00:00:00.88 bitrate=1178.0kbits/
    frame=   93 fps= 57 q=28.0 size=     164kB time=00:00:01.64 bitrate= 820.0kbits/
    frame=  113 fps= 52 q=28.0 size=     201kB time=00:00:02.44 bitrate= 676.3kbits/
    frame=  136 fps= 51 q=28.0 size=     245kB time=00:00:03.36 bitrate= 596.3kbits/
    frame=  157 fps= 49 q=28.0 size=     282kB time=00:00:04.20 bitrate= 550.2kbits/
    frame=  178 fps= 48 q=28.0 size=     324kB time=00:00:05.04 bitrate= 527.2kbits/
    frame=  199 fps= 47 q=28.0 size=     362kB time=00:00:05.88 bitrate= 504.1kbits/
    frame=  219 fps= 46 q=28.0 size=     403kB time=00:00:06.68 bitrate= 494.2kbits/
    frame=  242 fps= 46 q=28.0 size=     452kB time=00:00:07.60 bitrate= 486.8kbits/
    frame=  251 fps= 38 q=-1.0 Lsize=     623kB time=00:00:09.96 bitrate= 512.3kbits
    /s speed=1.52x
    video:619kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing o
    verhead: 0.607807%
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] frame I:2     Avg QP:21.74  size: 56596
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] frame P:66    Avg QP:23.36  size:  2523
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] frame B:183   Avg QP:31.50  size:  1932
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] consecutive B-frames:  0.8%  4.0%  6.0% 89.2%
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] mb I  I16..4: 10.9% 72.6% 16.5%
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.2%  P16..4:  4.4%  2.3
    %  3.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:89.7%
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.5%  B16..8:  3.2%  2.0
    %  2.3%  direct: 1.3%  skip:90.7%  L0:50.9% L1:42.2% BI: 7.0%
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] 8x8 transform intra:50.2% inter:10.1%
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 83.4% 32.6% 14.2% inter: 3
    .5% 0.2% 0.0%
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] i16 v,h,dc,p: 22%  8%  8% 62%
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 12% 19%  6%  9%
     9%  9%  9%  9%
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 14% 22%  6%  9%
     8%  8%  5%  6%
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] i8c dc,h,v,p: 74% 12% 12%  2%
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] ref P L0: 41.8%  3.9% 24.3% 30.0%
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] ref B L0: 64.5% 25.0% 10.5%
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] ref B L1: 82.2% 17.8%
    [libx264 @ 00000092cd5e3700] kb/s:504.56
```

Comment: Is it possible, the realized video playback in Processing isn't realtime i.e. your code/project may be 25 fps, but due to processing burden, it's outputting frames, during playback, at a lower rate, while playing the audio in realtime.

Comment: I see your point, but I don't think that is the reason as the animation is based on the music frequency, and when I have the video playback in Processing the animation matches to the beat of the music. Unlike when I render it with ffmpeg. I just tried to render it with Processes Movie Maker, and it did the exact same thing. Which makes me think that the issue lies in my Processing code.

Comment: https://vimeo.com/22992956 came across this link looks like I might have to analyze the audio separate?

Comment: Not conversant with Processing, so can't say. However, if you convert your MP3 to WAV, then maybe your current code can keep up.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you managed to get the sound and the video synchronized in the running program probably means you run it on a free CPU

If music and video are two separate threads (as I understand it) its not guaranteed that the CPU will run them always so.

So if you want to have your final video .mp4 synchronized you have to work outside the program: take them together to a video editing software and synchronize them.

But if you want them synchronized in the program you are fine.